# "Not IsNull" seems to be ignored

Tags: vba, ms-access, conditional-statements

I am working with some VBA code in Access that when a very specific set of conditions are met it will pop up an `InputBox` asking for a integer. So far so good.

```
Private Sub Command10_Click()

    If Not IsNull(mrf) Then
        If min <> max Then
            If qty <= min Then
                mrf = GetParamValue
            End If
        End If
    End If
    End Sub
```

The problem is that `Not IsNull` seems to be ignored. I would like it to ask for a value to be entered unless a value is already present. This keeps firing off the `InputBox` as long as the `min <> max` and `qty <= min` conditions are met.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Ahh looks like my problem is coming from someplace else.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If `mrf` is Variant, then it's initially `Empty`, not `Null`. You therefore have to use `IsEmpty()` function.

Comment: Another option would be to initialize mrf to null. I noticed he isn't declaring any of his variables (min, max, mrf) which is in general a bad idea. Turn on "Option Explicit" and you'll avoid a lot of logic bugs like this.

Answer (score 4):

No, the **Not IsNull** is working perfectly.

Remember, **IsNull** is a function which returns TRUE if the parameter passed to it is null, and false otherwise.

Your "If Not IsNull(mrf) Then" statement translates into english as "If mrf is not null then"

what that means is when mrf has a value, then you're processing the code inside the if statement. If you're wanting the inner code to fire when mrf IS null, then you need to remove the *NOT* from the statement.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that mrf isn't null, even if it's empty or something else.  It could also be Nothing, which is different from null in VBA land (I think).  Try running the code in the debugger and looking at the value of mrf.  Depending on what mrf is, you can do a different test (like check len(mrf) or not isNothing(mrf) or if it's an integer, and it's init to zero, then mrf <> 0.... you get the idea.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in this piece on VB6/VBA null/nothing/empty:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/30/53120.aspx